# Find indices of a list of values in a numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy master array.  Given another array of search values, with repeating elements, I want to produce the indices of these search values in the master array.

E.g.: master array is [1,2,3,4,5], search array is [4,2,2,3]

Solution:    [3,1,1,2]

Is there a "native" numpy function that does this efficiently (meaning at C speed, rather than python speed)?

I'm aware of the following solution, but, first, it's a python list comprehension, and second, it'll search for the index of 2 twice.

```
ma = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
sl = np.array([4,2,2,3])
ans = [np.where(ma==i) for i in sl]
```

Also, if I have to resort to sorting and binary search, I will do it as a last resort (puns not intended at all sorts of levels).  I am interested in finding if I'm missing something basic from the numpy library.  These lists are very large, so performance is paramount.

Thanks.

Edit: 
Before posting I'd tried the following with dismal results:

```
[np.searchsorted(ma,x) for x in sl]
```

The solution posted by @pierre is much more performant and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Would `np.searchsorted` work for you ?

```
>>> master = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> search = np.array([4,2,2,3])
>>> np.searchsorted(master, search)
array([3, 1, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Absolutely!  Just finished profiling your code and it works great. Will edit my question to post results.

Comment: Is there a non sorted version ?

Comment: This may not work well if the master isn't sorted or if there are values in search that aren't in master, but are smaller than the greatest value in master. For example, given `master = master = np.array([2,1,3,5,4])` and `search = np.array([4,2,0,3])`, the result of `np.searchsorted(master, search)` will be `array([3, 2, 0, 2])`.

Comment: failed for strings, for example, 'G100 will be returned for G10'