# Find indices of a list of values in a not sorted numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm referring to a similar question: [Find indices of a list of values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122639)

In that case we have a master array that is sorted and another array of which we want to find the index in the master array.

```
master = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
search = np.array([4,2,2,3])
```

The suggested solution was:

```
>>> master = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> search = np.array([4,2,2,3])
>>>np.searchsorted(master, search)
array([3, 1, 1, 2])
```

But what if master is not sorted?
for example if i have two arrays like this where the first one is not sorted:

```
>>>master = np.array([2,3,5,4,1])
>>>search = np.array([3,2,1,4,5])
```

i get:

```
>>> np.searchsorted(master, search)
array([1, 0, 0, 2, 5])
```

But instead i would like:

```
array([1,0,4,3,2])
```

i.e. the indices of items in search in master.

How do i get them possibly with a native function of numpy?(not using [np.where(master==i) for i in search] )

Thanks

EDIT: 
In this case the search array  is a permutation of master. Then i would like to find how the index of master are permuted to give a permuted array like search.

As general case, search array contain some item that maybe contained or not in the master such as:

```
>>>master = np.array([2,3,5,4,1])
>>>search = np.array([1,4,7])
```

Comment: Is this an XY question? Are you just trying to find a *permutation* of a given array? Because that can be easily done.

Comment: So do you want to avoid sorting then? The results are not what you expect because the algorithm behind `searchsorted` assumes the input to be sorted (like in binary search).

Comment: In my specific case search is a permutation of master (then i would mean to find the index of the permutation of master that results in the search array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I wrote this answer for [an earlier revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40021914/1). If you want to solve the problem in the appendix (when we aren't just looking for a permutation of an array), [see Will's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62421866/5067311).

If all else fails, you need to sort your master array temporarily, then invert the sort order needed for this after matching the elements:

```
import numpy as np

master = np.array([2,3,5,4,1])
search = np.array([3,2,1,4,5])

# sorting permutation and its reverse
sorti = np.argsort(master)
sorti_inv = np.empty(sorti.shape,dtype=np.int64)
sorti_inv[sorti] = np.arange(sorti.size)

# get indices in sorted version
tmpind = np.searchsorted(master,search,sorter=sorti)

# transform indices back to original array with inverse permutation
final_inds = tmpind[sorti_inv]
```

The result of the above is correctly

```
array([1, 0, 4, 3, 2])
```

---

As you noted in a comment, your specific `search` and `master` are permutations of each other. In this case you can alternatively sort *both* arrays, and use the inverse permutation combined with the other direct permutation:

```
sorti = np.argsort(master)
sorti_inv = np.empty(sorti.shape,dtype=np.int64)
sorti_inv[sorti] = np.arange(sorti.size)
sorti_s = np.argsort(search)
final_inds = sorti_s[sorti_inv]
```

One should consider the effort needed to search two arrays vs searching one array in the sorted version of another. I really can't tell which one's faster.

Comment: The first part of this answer is in general wrong (although it works for the test case provided) - assuming the question is asking for `final_inds` such that `np.array_equal(master[final_inds], search)` is `True`

Comment: @Will I'll take a closer look when I get a chance later, thanks. Judging by the timestamps it's possible I hadn't even seen the edit on the question.

Comment: @Will sorry, I forgot to follow up on your comment. You're right, as I suspected I hadn't seen the edit on the question. As a simplest solution I've put a disclaimer on top, pointing readers to your answer if they are looking for the more general problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to the original question. (The question Edit does not specify what should be returned when `search` is not a subset of `master`)

```
import numpy as np

def get_indices(master, search):

    if not set(search).issubset(set(master)):
        raise ValueError('search must be a subset of master')

    sorti = np.argsort(master)

    # get indices in sorted version
    tmpind = np.searchsorted(master,search,sorter=sorti)

    final_inds = sorti[tmpind]

    return final_inds


master = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 9, 0, 2, 7, 8])
search = np.array([6, 4, 3, 1, 1])

final_inds = get_indices(master, search)

assert( np.array_equal(master[final_inds], search) )
```

The result for `final_inds` is

```
array([3, 1, 0, 4, 4])
```