# How to replace a list of values in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have an unsorted array of numbers.

I need to replace certain numbers (given in a list) with specific alternatives (also given in a corresponding list)

I wrote the following code (which seems to works):

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.arange(0,40)
np.random.shuffle(numbers)
problem_numbers = [33, 23, 15]  # table, night_stand, plant
alternative_numbers = [12, 14, 26]  # desk, dresser, flower_pot

for i in range(len(problem_numbers)):
    idx = numbers == problem_numbers[i]
    numbers[idx] = alternative_numbers[i]
```

However, this seems highly inefficient (this needs to be done several millions of times for much larger arrays).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122639/find-indices-of-a-list-of-values-in-a-numpy-array) question which answers a similar problem however in my case the numbers are not sorted and they need to maintain their original location.

Note: `numbers` may contain multiple or no occurrences of elements in `problem_numbers`

Comment: why you code `idx = numbers == problem_numbers[i]`?Does `problem_numbers` need to be in the numbers range?

Comment: @itzikBenShabat Just another question: Do you want cascading replacements, for example if the problem numbers is `[1, 3]` and the alternatives are `[3, 5]` do you want a `1` in `numbers` to be `3` afterwards or `5`? Your solution converts it to `5` while not-cascading replacements would replace it with `3`.

Comment: No cacading is required. This is not a posible scenario with my data

Comment: @itzikBenShabat Can we assume unique numbers in `problem_numbers`?

Comment: @Divakar Yes. we can assume unique numbers in problem_numbers and alternative_numbers, but not in numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I implemented a TensorFlow version of this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56805806/1782792) (almost exactly the same, except replacements are a dict).

---

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.arange(0,40)
np.random.shuffle(numbers)
problem_numbers = [33, 23, 15]  # table, night_stand, plant
alternative_numbers = [12, 14, 26]  # desk, dresser, flower_pot

# Replace values
problem_numbers = np.asarray(problem_numbers)
alternative_numbers = np.asarray(alternative_numbers)
n_min, n_max = numbers.min(), numbers.max()
replacer = np.arange(n_min, n_max + 1)
# Mask replacements out of range
mask = (problem_numbers >= n_min) & (problem_numbers <= n_max)
replacer[problem_numbers[mask] - n_min] = alternative_numbers[mask]
numbers = replacer[numbers - n_min]
```

This works well an should be efficient as long as the range of the values in `numbers` (the difference between the smallest and the biggest) is not huge (e.g you don't have something like `1`, `7` and `10000000000`).

**Benchmarking**

I've compared the code in the OP with the three (as of now) proposed solutions with this code:

```
import numpy as np

def method_itzik(numbers, problem_numbers, alternative_numbers):
    numbers = np.asarray(numbers)
    for i in range(len(problem_numbers)):
        idx = numbers == problem_numbers[i]
        numbers[idx] = alternative_numbers[i]
    return numbers

def method_mseifert(numbers, problem_numbers, alternative_numbers):
    numbers = np.asarray(numbers)
    replacer = dict(zip(problem_numbers, alternative_numbers))
    numbers_list = numbers.tolist()
    numbers = np.array(list(map(replacer.get, numbers_list, numbers_list)))
    return numbers

def method_divakar(numbers, problem_numbers, alternative_numbers):
    numbers = np.asarray(numbers)
    problem_numbers = np.asarray(problem_numbers)
    problem_numbers = np.asarray(alternative_numbers)
    # Pre-process problem_numbers and correspondingly alternative_numbers
    # such that repeats and no matches are taken care of
    sidx_pn = problem_numbers.argsort()
    pn = problem_numbers[sidx_pn]
    mask = np.concatenate(([True],pn[1:] != pn[:-1]))
    an = alternative_numbers[sidx_pn]

    minN, maxN = numbers.min(), numbers.max()
    mask &= (pn >= minN) & (pn <= maxN)

    pn = pn[mask]
    an = an[mask]

    # Pre-pocessing done. Now, we need to use pn and an in place of
    # problem_numbers and alternative_numbers repectively. Map, index and assign.
    sidx = numbers.argsort()
    idx = sidx[np.searchsorted(numbers, pn, sorter=sidx)]
    valid_mask = numbers[idx] == pn
    numbers[idx[valid_mask]] = an[valid_mask]

def method_jdehesa(numbers, problem_numbers, alternative_numbers):
    numbers = np.asarray(numbers)
    problem_numbers = np.asarray(problem_numbers)
    alternative_numbers = np.asarray(alternative_numbers)
    n_min, n_max = numbers.min(), numbers.max()
    replacer = np.arange(n_min, n_max + 1)
    # Mask replacements out of range
    mask = (problem_numbers >= n_min) & (problem_numbers <= n_max)
    replacer[problem_numbers[mask] - n_min] = alternative_numbers[mask]
    numbers = replacer[numbers - n_min]
    return numbers
```

The results:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

MAX_NUM = 100000
numbers = np.random.randint(0, MAX_NUM, size=100000)
problem_numbers = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, MAX_NUM, size=500))
alternative_numbers = np.random.randint(0, MAX_NUM, size=len(problem_numbers))

%timeit method_itzik(numbers, problem_numbers, alternative_numbers)
10 loops, best of 3: 63.3 ms per loop

# This method expects lists
problem_numbers_l = list(problem_numbers)
alternative_numbers_l = list(alternative_numbers)
%timeit method_mseifert(numbers, problem_numbers_l, alternative_numbers_l)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.5 ms per loop

%timeit method_divakar(numbers, problem_numbers, alternative_numbers)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.45 ms per loop

%timeit method_jdehesa(numbers, problem_numbers, alternative_numbers)
1000 loops, best of 3: 822 µs per loop
```

Comment: This assumes elements in `numbers` cover the entire sequence from its min to max.

Comment: @Divakar No, it does not require `numbers` to cover the whole range, the values in `replacer` that are not in `numbers` will just not be used (which is why I say that having huge "gaps" in `numbers` may turn this inefficient, memory-wise at least).

Comment: Here's what I tried to get a random array that doesn't cover all numbers within the range : `numbers = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,100,(50)))` ; `numbers[10] = 23` ; `numbers[20] = 15` ; `numbers[30] = 33` and then shuffle. Value mis-match with this approach.

Comment: @Divakar Ohh right, there was an error in the code, thanks.

Comment: When you time functions that do some in-place operations you should be using a `setup` code that is executed before each timing run. That makes sure that subsequent runs aren't biased because the first run already modified the input.

Comment: Note that my approach assumed that the `problem_numbers` and `alternative_numbers` are lists. If they aren't it would be better (and faster) to use `replacer = dict(zip(problem_numbers.tolist(), alternative_numbers.tolist()))`

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks for the tip. Actually I ran the whole code again for each method, just put everything together here, although I did forget about seeding. I've changed the code to use lists in your method.

Comment: @jdehesa I didn't mean seeding. I meant that `%timeit` doesn't bother that the arrays changed between the loops. So while the first loop replaces the values correctly, the second loop will try to replace the values in the **changed** `numbers` array. That could (and will) bias the results of subsequent runs. That's why you need a setup command for `%timeit` in this case or make sure every function makes a copy before changing the original. i.e. `numbers = np.array(numbers, copy=True)`.

Comment: @jdehesa Something is not working right for me. I think that its in the case when the highest number in numbers is smaller than the highest number in problem_numbers

Comment: @itzikBenShabat Hmm, can you give more details about what is not working (e.g. you get an error, the result is not correct...), or a code example where it happens? I have tested a case like that and it seems to work for me...

Comment: @jdehesa, Yes - sorry . Try this `numbers = np.random.randint(0,30,(15))
numbers[0] = 23
numbers[1] = 23
numbers[2] = 33
numbers[3] = 15` as input. The 33 in element 2 does not change ( no error)

Comment: @itzikBenShabat Ahh shoot, I used `<` where it should have been `<=`. Should work now...

Answer (score 2):

#### In case not all `problem_values` are in `numbers` and they may even occur multiple times:

In that case I would just use a `dict` to keep the values to be replaced and use `dict.get` to translate problematic numbers:

```
replacer = dict(zip(problem_numbers, alternative_numbers))
numbers_list = numbers.tolist()
numbers = np.array(list(map(replacer.get, numbers_list, numbers_list)))
```

Even though it has to go "through Python" this is almost self-explaining and it's not much slower than a NumPy solution (probably).

#### In case every `problem_value` is actually present in the `numbers` array and **only** once:

If you have the [`numpy_indexed`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-indexed) package you could simply use `numpy_indexed.indices`:

```
>>> import numpy_indexed as ni
>>> numbers[ni.indices(numbers, problem_numbers)] = alternative_numbers
```

That should be pretty efficient even for big arrays.

Comment: There is an extra argument in `map`. Using `map` over `numbers` (you can pass it directly as array instead of converting it to `list`) is probably not better than iterating over `problem_numbers`, which is apparently smaller, as the OP does.

Comment: @jdehesa The constant factor in iterating over an `array` is much higher than iterating over a list (even if one has to use `tolist`) so if performance is a concern and python-iteration is required **always convert to a list**!

Comment: @jdehesa The extra argument is because `dict.get` takes two arguments.